# How to append unique incoming messages to a list?

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, paho

I am using a RFID reader to receive messages. I'm trying to avoid duplicated message by appending them to `emptylist = []` and don't further append them if they exist in the list. Below are my code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("/whatver/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg): # when PUBLISH msg is rcvd frm the server
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]


    payload = {'a': epc[11:35], 'b':payloadjson["devicename"], 'c':payloadjson["sensorname"]}

    emptylist = []
    emptylist.append(payload)

    if payload not in emptylist:
        emptylist.append(payload)

    print (emptylist)

test = mqtt.Client(protocol = mqtt.MQTTv31)
test.connect(host=_host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
test.on_connect = on_connect
test.on_message = on_message
test.loop_forever()
```

However I am getting output as below, which shows that `payload` is appended to the `emptylist`, but is stored into multiple separated lists.  And it keeps printing the same output if the RFID reader is still reading the same tag. I would like to remove the duplicated messages and retain only one even if the RFID reader reads the same tag.

```
[{'b': 'READERBASIN.3', 'c': 'ANTENNA.2', 'a': '000000000000130000624462'}] # from Tag A
[{'b': 'READERBASIN.3', 'c': 'ANTENNA.2', 'a': 'abcxxx000000130000627000'}] # from Tag B
[{'b': 'READERBASIN.3', 'c': 'ANTENNA.2', 'a': '000000000000130000624462'}] # from Tag A
[{'b': 'READERBASIN.3', 'c': 'ANTENNA.2', 'a': '000000000000130000624462'}] # from Tag A
.
.
.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers mention, a set is a great way to avoid storing or printing duplicates. You *can* do this (less efficiently) using lists, however, the logic in your current code is incorrect. It creates a fresh empty `emptylist` every time that `on_message` is called, and then appends the new `payload` to it, so the following `if payload not in emptylist:` doesn't make much sense.

You need to initialize `emptylist` outside of the `on_message` callback. Eg,

```
emptylist = []

def on_message(client, userdata, msg): # when PUBLISH msg is rcvd frm the server
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]

    payload = {
        'a': epc[11:35], 
        'b':payloadjson["devicename"], 
        'c':payloadjson["sensorname"],
    }

    if payload not in emptylist:
        emptylist.append(payload)
        print (emptylist)
```

That will only append & print the new payload if it's not already in `emptylist`.

To do the same thing using a set:

```
emptylist = set()

def on_message(client, userdata, msg): # when PUBLISH msg is rcvd frm the server
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]

    payload = {
        'a': epc[11:35], 
        'b':payloadjson["devicename"], 
        'c':payloadjson["sensorname"],
    }

    if payload not in emptylist:
        emptylist.add(payload)
        print (emptylist)
```

FWIW, `emptylist` is a slightly confusing variable name. :)

Comment: Thanks for this great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can check for existence while appending as below:

```
if payload not in emptylist:
   emptylist.append(payload)
```

or

You can choose `set(emptylist)` on your final output.